# Can a triangle plot be used for metrics that do not sum to 100%?

Tags: r, data-visualization, scales, dimensions

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot):

> A ternary plot, ternary graph, triangle plot, simplex plot, or de Finetti diagram is a barycentric plot on three variables which sum to a constant.

However, I want to use the plot to map 3 variables on one observation:

- Efficiency, measured in seconds
- Revenue generated, measured in £
- Customer satisfaction, measured in %

I don't want to use a 3D scatter plot, as I only have one observation (in this case, one call centre).

My question is, **can I construct a ternary plot (preferably in R) with data on different scales not summing to 100%**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a ternary plot is only able to collapse three dimensions into two because the third variable is dependent on the other two. `z = 100% - x - y`.

Instead, you might try a 2D scatter plot for two of your variables and color for the third variable.